# How can I dismiss view controller or unwind from it from NotificationCenter observer?

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I'm new to iOS development so I feel like I'm missing some fundamental knowledge here.

I have view controller (VC) that displays some information that comes form the server. My VC has two notification center observers - one for successful response from server and one for error.

I added observers like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(getPlaceInfoFailed:)
                                                 name:kGetPlaceInfoRequestDidFailBlockNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

In case of error I want to display alert and navigate to previous view controller. Let's name them view controllers `A` and `B`.

I'm using storyboards.

My problem is that when I return to `A` UI is completely messed up - navigation bar has random stuff, my table view has garbage and etc. Eventually app crashes.

Here is how I tried to dismiss my VC `B`

```
- (void)getPlaceInfoFailed:(NSNotification *)notification {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
        //[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
        //[self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];

        //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"exitSegue" sender:self];
    });
}
```

Version `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"exitSegue" sender:self];` works when I invoke it, for example, in button action handler.

But not in observer :( As you can see I tried to invoke `performSegue` in UI thread - no difference.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you!!!

Comment: why are you trying to dimiss within dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{} any reasons?

Comment: @satheeshwaran I did it out of desperation. I thought maybe notification center observer is invoked within non-UI thread and that's why entire UI gets screwed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my problem was that I was calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` before `viewDidAppear` and that why it didn't work.

How I can handle two asynchronous events - view creation and requesting server I don't know yet.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is just dismiss the VC when the notification fires and handle the UI mishap in viewWillAppear of your parent controller/presenting controller - VC A.

This code should be in B if I am not wrong

```
- (void)getPlaceInfoFailed:(NSNotification *)notification {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES]; or try
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //dep'd in ios 6.


}
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither option worked :( it doesn't mess up UI though. It just stays in `B` like nothing happened.

Comment: Did the notification get fired?

Comment: You know. It looks like the problem lies in the fact that code that creates notification is called from `viewDidLoad`. I just tried putting button on the view, invoked network code from button action handler and did the same `performSegueWithIdentifier` from observer and it worked without any problems. What do you think about it ?

Comment: That would not be the reason because the notification is fired asynchronously after the service call has completed. Can you post the code where you segue B controller or present B controller.